# Break functions to Jquery deferred or promise

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I have following code. Once to load HTML page, other for loading different subsections and binding callback functions with buttons. Can you tell me how to break two ajax calls into promise and once successful then only bind events to button

```
function loadHtml(methodargs){

    header=methodargs.header;
    htmlname=methodargs.htmlname;
    subsection=methodargs.subsection;
    callbackfunction=methodargs.callbackfunction;
    buttonfunctioanlities = methodargs.buttons;


    $("#mainContentSubmit").off('click');
    $('#maincontentbody').empty();

    $("#maincontentheader").html(header);

    //Function 1
    if(htmlname != '')
       $( "#maincontentbody" ).load( ctx+"/loadpage?pagename="+htmlname, function( response, status, xhr ) {
          if ( status != "error" ) {
                $.each(callbackfunction, function( index, value ) {
                    window[value]();
                });
          }
        });

    //Function 2
    $.each(subsection,function(index,value){
        var data = {
                attributeName : value,
                orgid : $('#orgidselector').find("option:selected").val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: ctx+'orgattr/getAttributePage.json',
            dataType: "html",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                $('#maincontentbody').append(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert("getAttributePage error :"+jqXHR+":"+textStatus+":"+errorThrown);
                console.log( "getAttributePage error :"+jqXHR+":"+textStatus+":"+errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });

    //Bind callback functions with buttons
    $.each(buttonfunctioanlities, function(k, v) {
        formsubmitFunction=v.submitFunction;
        formsubmitFunctionArgs=v.submitFunctionArgs;
        submitbuttonid=v.submitbuttonid;
        if(formsubmitFunction != ''){
            if(formsubmitFunctionArgs.legth == 0){
                $("#"+submitbuttonid).off('click').on('click', window[formsubmitFunction]);
            }else{
                $("#"+submitbuttonid).off('click').on('click', formsubmitFunctionArgs, window[formsubmitFunction]);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by putting deferred requests into an array

```
function loadHtml(methodargs){

    header=methodargs.header;
    htmlname=methodargs.htmlname;
    subsection=methodargs.subsection;
    callbackfunction=methodargs.callbackfunction;
    buttonfunctioanlities = methodargs.buttons;


    $("#mainContentSubmit").off('click');
    $('#maincontentbody').empty();

    $("#maincontentheader").html(header);
    var ajaxrequests = [];
    if(htmlname != ''){
        /*ajaxrequests.push($( "#maincontentbody" ).load( ctx+"/loadpage?pagename="+htmlname), function( response, status, xhr ) {
            console.log('response :'+response);
        });*/
        ajaxrequests.push(
            $.ajax({
                url: ctx+"/loadpage?pagename="+htmlname,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    //$( "#maincontentbody" ).html($(data));
                    return data;
                }
            })
        );
    }

    $.each(subsection,function(index,value){
        var data = {
                attributeName : value,
                orgid : $('#orgidselector').find("option:selected").val()
        };

        ajaxrequests.push(
            $.ajax({
                url: ctx+'orgattr/getAttributePage.json',
                dataType: "html",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                },
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    return data;

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    alert("getAttributePage error :"+jqXHR+":"+textStatus+":"+errorThrown);
                    console.log( "getAttributePage error :"+jqXHR+":"+textStatus+":"+errorThrown);
                }
            })
      );
    });

    $.when.apply($, ajaxrequests).then(function( data ) {
        $.each(arguments, function (i, data) {
            console.log(data); //data is the value returned by each of the ajax requests

            $('#maincontentbody').append(data);
        });

        $.each(callbackfunction, function( index, value ) {
            window[value]();
        });
    }).then(function( data ) {
        //Move to different block
        $.each(buttonfunctioanlities, function(k, v) {
            formsubmitFunction=v.submitFunction;
            formsubmitFunctionArgs=v.submitFunctionArgs;
            submitbuttonid=v.submitbuttonid;
            if($("#"+submitbuttonid).length){
                if(formsubmitFunction != ''){
                    if(formsubmitFunctionArgs.length == 0){
                        $("#"+submitbuttonid).off('click').on('click', window[formsubmitFunction]);
                    }else{
                        $("#"+submitbuttonid).off('click').on('click', formsubmitFunctionArgs, window[formsubmitFunction]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```